# Element type invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to loop out some partner logos from a headless CMS, but whenever I try to use React-components in my file I get an error stating

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Partners`.
```

I can use my map functions as pure javascript functions but when I try to use them as React components I get this error.

What I want to work

```
  const SinglePartner = ({partner}) => {
    return (
      <Col sm="6" md="3" lg="4" className="logoScaling">
        <h4 className="text-center">{partner.title}</h4>
        <img
          src={partner.partnerLogo.asset.url}
          alt={partner.partnerLogo.alt}
          className="partnerLogos"
        />
      </Col>
    )   }

  const PartnerLooper = partners.map((partner) => {
    return <SinglePartner key={partner._key} />    })
```

When debugging I tried simplifying my components, re-writing my PartnerLooper to

```
  const PartnerLooper = partners.map((partner) => {
    return <p>{partner.name}</p>
  })
```

Using this method I can call PartnerLooper as a javascript function but not as a react component

```
return(
          {/* Returns errror */}
         <PartnerLooper />
         {/* Works  */}
         {PartnerLooper}
)
```

Full component code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";


const Partners = ({ partners }) => {
  
  const PartnerLooper = partners.map((partner) => {
    return <SinglePartner partner={partner} /> 
  })

  const SinglePartner = ({partner}) => {
    return (
      <Col sm="6" md="3" lg="4" className="logoScaling">
        <h4 className="text-center">{partner.title}</h4>
        <img
          src={partner.partnerLogo.asset.url}
          alt={partner.partnerLogo.alt}
          className="partnerLogos"
        />
      </Col>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="container pt-8 pt-md-10 partnerPadding" role="region">
      <section aria-label="Partners">
        <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
         <PartnerLooper />
        </Row>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Partners;
```

See the datastructure I am working with here
https://pastebin.com/MFGh1xuY

EDIT: I am running  `"gatsby": "^2.22.15"` and "react": `"^16.12.0",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning an array of elements to `PartnerLooper` and then using it as a component `<PartnerLooper/>` in the `Partners` component. you can insert an element array directly as a child in JSX.

Replace the returned JSX with

```
<div className="container pt-8 pt-md-10 partnerPadding" role="region">
  <section aria-label="Partners">
    <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
      {PartnerLooper} 
    </Row>
  </section>
</div>
```

If you meant to render one `Row` per partner, <ou can achieve that like this:

```
return (
  <div className="container pt-8 pt-md-10 partnerPadding" role="region">
    <section aria-label="Partners">
      {partners.map(partner =>
        <Row className="justify-content-md-center" key={partner._key}>
          <SinglePartner partner={partner} /> 
        </Row>
      )}
    </section>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I don't see any "`PartnerLogo`" here. Also, you are accessing `partner.title` while that data only has `partner.name`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you DustInCompetent, your answer helped me

I did not want to run map directly in JSX because I think it is a bit ugly, I solved this by wrapping my SinglePartner and PartnerLooper-components in a parent component and using the return from this component. Full code:

```
const Partners = ({ partners }) => {

  const AllPartners = () => {
    const SinglePartner = ({ partner }) => {
      return (
        <Col sm="6" md="3" lg="4" className="logoScaling">
          <h4 className="text-center">{partner.name}</h4>
          <img
            src={partner.partnerLogo.asset.url}
            alt={partner.partnerLogo.alt}
            className="partnerLogos"
          />
        </Col>
      )
    }
    const PartnerLooper = partners.map((partner) => {
      return <SinglePartner partner={partner} />
    })
    return PartnerLooper
  }


  return (
    <div className="container pt-8 pt-md-10 partnerPadding" role="region">
      <section aria-label="Partners">
        <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
          <AllPartners />
        </Row>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Partners;
```

Comment: remember to fix `partner.title` to `partner.name`